# Does "meteor login" command store a cookie somewhere?

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor.

I just ran [meteor deploy](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteordeploy) on my laptop for the first time.

It asked my e-mail address and then did the deploy.

Next, I used that e-mail account to verify my meteor account.

On my laptop when I run `meteor whoami` it knows who I am.

I looked around under `~/.meteor` and did not see an obvious file or folder holding my login state.

so did anyones know where is meteor storing this state information on my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

technically you are login in into the [meteor tool](https://www.meteor.com/services/developer-accounts), and actually there is not information about how that OAuth2 works.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor doesn't use session cookies, instead it uses session tokens in localstorage. More info here:

https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/03/14/session-cookies